# Showing an alert with Cocoa

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have been using VB.NET for a while and I switched to Xcode 4.

In the VB.NET environment, I used to type the following command in a button:

```
if TextBox1.text="" then
    MessageBox.Show("You can't leave the textbox empty!, "Error!")
else
    Label1.text = TextBox1.text
```

That is just an example. In Xcode, I want to do the same thing except for I want to have a Pop-Up Alert (in the iPhone) instead of the MessageBox in VB.NET.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Read how to use UIAlertView in iphone sdk.

Comment: +1 for switching to XCode 4 and iOS. Welcome ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go

```
if ([TextBox1.text isEqualToString:@""]){
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                         message:@"You can't leave the textbox empty!"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
    [errorAlert release];
} else {
    Label1.text = TextBox1.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Rahul Vyas
I am trying to build a calculator that will multiply the value of textField1 by the value of textField2 and display the answer on label1 when the button "Calculate" is pressed.
And I want it to show that message if either of the textbox's was left empty.

Can you tell me what I've done wrong here?
[link](http://f.cl.ly/items/2u2M1p2E1y0F3V1u1S1n/Screen%20shot%202011-06-21%20at%203.17.48%20PM.png)

Comment: @Faisal - what you've done wrong is that you've assumed that programming iOS is going to be similar to programming anything else, just using different keywords. What you need to do is start reading the documents and then asking questions such as "How do I validate a text box"?

Comment: @Abizem - I think I will figure that out. But how about the previous command? I mean this message will only show when the textField1 is empty. I want it to show whether textField1 or textField2 are empty.

Comment: @Faisal how about using a or condition use it like this if ([TextBox1.text isEqualToString:@""] || if [TextBox2.text isEqualToString:@""])