# Display a new view from within a custom control

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a custom button which inherits from UIButton. I'm handling the TouchUpInside event and want to display a view on top of the current View. Is there such a thing as Dialogs like in Windows development? Or should I do this in another way?

```
[MonoTouch.Foundation.Register("HRPicker")]
public class HRPicker : UIButton
{
    public HRPicker () : base()
    {
        SetUp();
    }

    public HRPicker(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
    {
        SetUp();
    }

    public HRPicker(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
    {
        SetUp();
    }

    public HRPicker(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        SetUp();
    }

    public HRPicker(RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
    {
        SetUp();
    }

    public void SetUp()
    {
        TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;
    }

    void HandleTouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I want to display a View here on top of the current one.
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have a couple options:

- ModalViewController - is called from any UIViewController and overlays a ViewController in the foreground.
- UIPopoverController - is a native control that takes a UIViewController and has hooks for presentation and dismissal
- WEPopoverController - is a re-implementation of UIPopoverController and allows you to customize the layout, size, and color of the Popover container.

ModalViewController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

UIPopoverController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

WEPopoverController: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/WEPopover

**Update:** Regardless of which option you use you must call the presentation of the Popover / Modal view from the *main thread*:

```
using(var pool = new NSAutoReleasePool()) {
    pool.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{

        // Run your awesome code on the 
        // main thread here, dawg.

    });
}
```

Comment: The UIPopoverController was what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of dialog in Cocoa is UIAlertView: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Check out this question for an example of how to use it: [Showing an alert with Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424891/showing-an-alert-with-cocoa)

The code should be pretty easy to translate to c# and MonoTouch. But here is a simple example: http://monotouchexamples.com/#19

Comment: Well, that is an Alert Dialog. I'm talking about show another view as a dialog, not an alert